# How to stretch div content with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap on a website and I have some issues. I used a tab panel with bootstrap and I searched a lot, but it looks like I can't find a solution to dead spaces. I made a bootply project here

http://www.bootply.com/2PMTAAMyJL

And a screenshot 
http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/ErroresCSS_zps5ef1ca5f.png

How can I stretch that content and the Google maps div?

Comment: can you upload the part that should be worked on? nobody wanna go through that whole code

Comment: Aint nobody got time for that. Sorry, had to!

Comment: Resumed bootply, the content inside all tabs is the issue, the have not 100% width

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, i already tried that, not fixing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "label" elements need

```
width: 100%;
```

But as @DavidG already mentioned: use [Bootstrap Horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) to align your prompts and fields horizontal!

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing clue